# How to access Wordpress posts/data in an iOS app

Tags: ios, wordpress

I am writing an iOS app for a web site. This site is built using Wordpress. I have the overall UI structure built but I don't know I can connect to the sites server to get the needed data (posts, post titles, etc) to display through the app.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, if the site is configured in the usual way, you can add `?feed=rss2` to the URL of your WordPress-driven site to request an RSS2 feed.

Basically, you're going to [NSURLConnection and the URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) to fetch the RSS feed, and then parse it.  You can then use [NSXMLParser to read the feed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html), and turn it into data collections and/or model objects to hold the data.  Your UI can then load and display that data as you like.